# Redis as a cache manager + session manager (Data structuring using redis data type)

Tags: caching, redis

i am trying to use  redis as a cache and as a session manager.
I have my user base in which each user has a unique ID (83837XXX1,83837XXX2 ) and under that i need to hold some information  as mentioned in the below figure. Here, i want to know which data types should i use and how, to make it memory efficient.

```
83837XXX1   ----|------>Profile---------> (key,values)
                |       
                |------>Transactions |--> Credits --> (keys,values)
                |                    |
                |                    |-->xyz. --> (keys,values)
                |
                |------>Session_Web  --> (keys, values)
                |
                |
                |------>Session_App  -->(keys, values)


83837XXXX2  ----|------>Profile---------> (key,values)
                |       
                |------>Transactions |--> Credits --> (keys,values)
                |                    |
                |                    |-->xyz. --> (keys,values)
                |
                |------>Session_Web  --> (keys, values)
                |
                |
                |------>Session_App  -->(keys, values)
. .. . . . . .  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  .. 
. .. . . . . .  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  .. 
. .. . . . . .  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  ..
```

Comment: It mostly depends on how you want to use the data

Comment: I believe this question is related to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150219/how-to-use-redis-to-store-hierarchical-data.